# How to load JSON into AMP page?

Tags: json, amp-html

I have a **AMP page** and i need to make it dynamic. How to **load Json in AMP** page? My json code inside the AMP page shows '*Not a valid AMP page*' Error.

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it - AMP is static HTML ( you can add dynamic only from server-side which generate the page )

Either you can check `amp-state`. See https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/interactivity/remote-data for more details

```
  <amp-state id="selected">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "slide": 0,
        "sku": "1001"
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any video tutorial available for AMP development?

Comment: @HelloWorld text-tutorial is pretty good https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/es/docs/reference/components/amp-list)

> The amp-list component fetches dynamic content from a CORS JSON endpoint. The response from the endpoint contains data, which is rendered in the specified template.